# Recover gitlab got permission denied

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I host a gitlab-ce with docker image and start with docker compose.
Here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce'
    container_name: 'gitlab-master'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'url'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://url:9090'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
    networks:
      - gitlab-network
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '9090:9090'
      - '2224:22'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
networks:
  gitlab-network:
    name: gitlab-network
```

I pack my config folders, logs and data and transfer to another server. When I start a new gitlab server and mount this folders. I got the permission denied error. I use `chmod -R 777 /srv/gitlab/*`. It still error. How could I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/permission-denied-opt-gitlab-embedded-service-gitlab-shell-bin-gitlab-keys/5228), check also the permission of the parent folders.

> For some reason permissions to `/opt` was 700 instead of 755.
>   After I change it, everything works

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21242#note_14755486 can be interesting as well, but might not apply here.

Comment: Yah, I have saw that article before. But I am used docker compose not the install package. I don't know how to change to permission when docker compose up.

Comment: @Rukeith You could simply make your own image (Dockerfile + `docker build`) based on the image you want to run in your docker-compose, and do a `docker exec -it <yourImage> bash`, in order to have a look around. That will allow you just to check the permissions associated with /opt.